# Название почтовых станций

Tags: этимология

Почему раньше почтовые станции назывались ямами? Имеет ли это отношение к слову "яма"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Связи нет. 
Яма - праслявянское jama. Древнее, как минимум - индоевропейское. Родственные слова есть в греческом, латинском и проч.

Ям - из тюркских. Исходное значение по Фасмеру не восстанавливается. Я предполагаю что-то связнное с лошадьми. Согласно Фасмеру в современном уйгурском есть jam - c аналогичным русскому значению.
У него же, правда, говорится, что ямщик - слово правлавянское, что противоречит тюркской версии слова "ям". Но тут я не могу комментировать. Во всяком случае родство с "ямой" исключено.
~~~~
Добавлю. Цыганенко возводит тюркское jam не к лошадям, а к почте. 
А слово "ямщик" не считает древним. Получается, что Фасмер ошибается.
Но на основном выводе о неродсвенности "ям" и "яма" это никак не сказывается.